# Programming the nearest neighbor algorithm in Python 3.6

Tags: python, nearest-neighbor

I am very new to programming and might have bitten off more than I can chew. I am trying to create a program that allows me to find the shortest route to visit all of the National Parks by importing a csv file containing the park names and distances between each park. Ideally, I would like it to prompt the user for which park they would like to start with and then run through the other parks to find the shortest distance (e.g. if you wanted to start with Yellowstone, it would find the closest park to Yellowstone, then the closest park to that park, etc., then add up all those distances, returning the total mileage and the order the parks were visited in) I think I need to be importing the csv file as a dictionary so I can use the park names as keys, but I'm not sure then how to work the keys into the algorithm. So far I have the following put together from my limited knowledge:

```
import csv
import numpy as np

distances = csv.DictReader(open("ds.csv"))

for row in distances:
    print(row)
startingPark = input('Which park would you like to test?')

def NN(distanceArray, start):    
    path = [start]
    cost = 0
    N = A.shape[0]
    mask = np.ones(N, dtype=bool)
    mask[start] = False

    for i in range(N-1):
        last = path[-1]
        next_ind = np.argmin(distanceArray[last][mask]) # find minimum of remaining locations
        next_loc = np.arange(N)[mask][next_ind] # convert to original location
        path.append(next_loc)
        mask[next_loc] = False
        cost += distanceArray[last, next_loc]

    return path, cost
print (NN(distanceArray,0))
```

I know that I have to change all of the array stuff in the actual algorithm part of the code (that's just some code I was able to find through research on here that I am using as a starting point), but I am unsure of A: how to get it to actually use the input I give and B: how to make the algorithm work with the dictionary instead of with arrays that are input as part of the code itself. I've tried using the documentation and such, but it goes a bit over my head. Obviously I don't want anyone to just do it for me, but I'd appreciate any pointers or resources that people may have. I'm trying very hard to learn, but with no real guidance from anyone that knows what they're doing, I'm having a hard time.

Edit: Here is a sample of the data I have to work with. I pulled all of the distances from Google Maps and input them into a csv file. I think the x's I have in place might also be a problem and might need to be replaced with 0's or something similar, but I haven't gotten to handling that issue yet. (Sorry for not just uploading the picture, not enough rep to post one yet)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fscgq.jpg

Comment: What is the data you have access to? Do you have the coordinates of all these parks? Can you show us a sample of the data please.

Comment: An unrelated sub-note; this algorithm has always interested me because  as far as we've discovered there is no way to predict the maximum amount of run time to find the shortest path. IE there is no predictable time to answer

Comment: I've edited my post to include a screenshot of the data.

Comment: I hope you don't actually care about how correct your results are, because they are likely to be way off.  Also, I could help you if you had a plaintext version of this file.  But I am not familiar with .csv.  Looks like excel or something?

If you have skype or facebook chat or something I can help you.  This is more of a discussion and gradual learning type thing, not really an appropriate post for stackoverflow.